# Prestashop product upload with csv error

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I am trying to upload csv file of products in prestashop. Below are the errors that I am getting :

> No Name (ID: 61,1,Orous Women's A Line Dress,Home,1399,IN Reduced Rate (4%),0,0,,,,,D2_Yellow,,,,,,,,,,,2,,,,,,"Fabric: Crepe A-line
>   Exquisite style patterns Gentle machine wash, dry clean, do not
>   bleach",,,,,,,,,1,,,,http://www.spademark.com/1154X1500/orous/D2_Yellow-_1.jpg,,,,New,,,,,,,,)
>   cannot be saved

and

> Property Product->name is empty

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

docs http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/CSV+Import+Parameters

Please use this structure for successful upload:

"Enabled";"Name";"Categories";"Price";"Tax rule ID";"Buying price";"On sale";"Reference";"Weight";"Quantity";"Short desc.";"Long desc";"Images URL"

1;"Test";"1,2,3";130;1;75;0;"PROD-TEST";"0.500";10;"'Tis a short desc.";"This is a long description.";"http://www.myprestashop/images/product1.gif"